# how to use a sub query from Dual table within an Oracle insert command?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

This command should insert a record whose one of fields is millisecond, which gets by a sub query, into a table but returns an error. What is the problem?

```
insert into table1 values ( select trunc( (to_date('2019-11-26 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) * power(60, 2) * 24 * power(10, 3)) from dual, 0, 0, 0);
```

Error report -
SQL Error:
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: Why not `* 60*60*24*1000` - would be simpler in my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query,

Also you can Specify the columns names in the query

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, col3 ...) ( select trunc( (to_date('2019-11-26 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) * power(60, 2) * 24 * power(10, 3)),0, 0, 0 from dual);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into table1 
    select trunc( (to_date('2019-11-26 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) * power(60, 2) * 24 * power(10, 3)),
           0, 0, 0
from dual;
```

The `values` keyword is not necessary.  However, you should be including the list of columns for the table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a SELECT and you should always specify the column for INSERT:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
values (
   trunc( (to_date('2019-11-26 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - DATE '1970-01-01') * 60*60*24*1000), 0, 0, 0
   );
```

Note, I assume you like to calculate a Javascript timestamp or similar. This is the number of Milliseconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**`. For precise values (i.e. if Milliseconds matters) and proper time zone handling you should use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `DATE`. For example like this:

```
TRUNC((TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-11-26 01:00:00.00 Europe/Zurich', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC') *  60*60*24*1000)
```